# Read multiple vcards from one file using cardme

Tags: java, vcf-vcard

Is there a way how to read multiple vcards from only one file using cardme? According to examples show [here](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/cardme/index.php?title=Reading_a_VCard) it seems that it's not possible.

Comment: Updated the cardme wiki site to include an example of parsing a file containing multiple vcards inside it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no build in method to do this. You can iterate the file line by line until `END:VCARD` and then use the method `VCardEngine.parse(String)` to read each VCard one by one.

Something like this may work:

```
BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("allcards.txt"));

VCardEngine engine = new VCardEngine();
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
List<VCard> vcards = new ArrayList<VCard>();

String line;
while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
    builder.append(line);

    if (line.contains("END:VCARD")) {
        VCard vcard = engine.parse(builder.toString());
        vcards.add(vcard);
        builder = new StringBuilder();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if the method parseMultiple() is newer than this post, but this is actually possible with the versión I'm using (v0.3.3).

Here's a method that iterates over a Files array, in which each file may have multiple vcards, and adds all the read VCards to a List.

```
public List<VCard> importVCards() {
    List<VCard> vcards = new ArrayList<VCard>();
    vcardFiles = getFiles();        
    for(int i = 0; i < vcardFiles.length; i++){
        try {               
            vcards.addAll(vcardEngine.parseMultiple(vcardFiles[i]));
        }
        catch(IOException ioe) {
            System.err.println("Could not read vcard file:
                "+vcardFiles[i].getAbsolutePath());
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return vcards;
}
```

cardme can be found here:https://github.com/george-haddad/cardme

Answer (score 0):

Cardme version 0.3.3 has been released which supports parsing multiple vcards from 1 file. You can download it here http://sourceforge.net/projects/cardme/files/Cardme/Card%20Me%20Version%200.3.3/